# Get hour data from yahoo finance

Tags: yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

How can I get finance gata from yahoo.finance in realtime? I tried `select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata` but there only data by day not by hours.

Comment: You're querying a table called `historicaldata` -- I assume that it probably updated less often than the "live" table. Try looking at `yahoo.finance.quotes` instead.

Comment: `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = "FB"` gave me only last hour data :(
I need data to schedule changing price for last 12 hours(or more).

Comment: It's incredibly expense for Yahoo to subscribe to market feeds, the schedule on which they turn around and give rates to users freely will of course have limitations. You may want to look into other feeds.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ Could you answer something on this question and I close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're querying a table called `historicaldata`, it is probably only updated once a day. Another table, `quotes`, may have data updated on a more frequent timer (hourly, as you've mentioned).

Unfortunately, I think you've run into a limitation of Yahoo's free financial data feeds. They have to purchase market feeds from the source (NASDAQ, NYSE, etc.) (or close to it) and those feeds aren't cheap. If you want truly real-time data, that's something you'll probably have to cough good money out for.

There are other sources besides Yahoo though that might get you down to 15 minute updates. I will leave that research as an exercise for you since that's out of scope for StackOverflow. If you do find a different source and are having trouble reading from it, do please feel free to ask another question here! The more closely related to actual programming the better response you'll get from the community.